# Angular built-in-direcitives not working with Foundation components

Tags: angular, html, zurb-foundation, angular-directive

I am using a lot of the foundation components such modal , accordian and more. In my html in angular these work fine, but soon as I use built in directives from such *ngIf or *ngFor these foundation components completely stops working. Example below.

```
 <p><button class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</button></p>
  <h2 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <div *ngif="name === 'John'" class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
 </div>
```

The modal for this doesnt work , but the moment I remove the `*ngIf` it works well. 
What is the reason for this behaviour?

This code is what the main issue is about. and its not working when I decided to introduce the structural directives with real data.

```
<div class="app-dashboard-sidebar-inner">
    <div>{{topLabel}}</div>
    <ul class="vertical menu accordion-menu" data-accordion-menu>
    <ng-template ngFor let-asideItem [ngForOf]="asideItems">
      <li>
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" href="#">
            <i class="{{asideItem.icon}}"></i>
            <span class="app-dashboard-sidebar-text">{{asideItem.name}}</span>
          </a>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="asideItem.type === 'sub'">
            <ul class="menu vertial nested">
            <ng-template ngFor let-asideChildren [ngForOf]="asideItem.children">
                <li>
                    <span class="app-dashboard-sidebar-text">{{asideChildren.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ng-template>
          </ul>
          </ng-template>
      </li>
     </ng-template>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

All information are shown correctly but the dropdown accordian just doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, to anyone who might face the same problem the solution that worked for me was to call `$(document).foundation();` in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
$(document).foundation();
```

}

Comment: @user3701188 I am facing the same problem the moment I introduce structural directives my modals or dropdown stop working. I get this error in my console.
  `Uncaught TypeError: elem.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at Object.GetDimensions (foundation.js:1117)
    at Dropdown._setPosition (foundation.js:3628)
    at Dropdown._setPosition (foundation.js:5807)
    at Dropdown.open (foundation.js:5940)
    at Dropdown.toggle (foundation.js:6004)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)
  `

Comment: Any solution for me. I am added `ngAfterViewInit(): void {
                $(document).foundation();

   }` but still no success

Answer (score 0):

Just use structure directive in `ng-template`.

example:

```
<ng-template *ngif="name === 'John'">
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have tried it and its not working as well. I am trying to use structural directives example ngFor with the components such as accordian. I have updated my question to incude the code I am using for the accordian

Comment: check your comment and also I have edited my edited to add more info. Please do check

Comment: All information are shown correctly but the dropdown accordian just doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it can't work is that `ngIf` doesn't create the DOM(id='exampleModal1') when the condition is `false`, so `data-open="exampleModal1"` can't find target DOM

you can use `hidden` instead of `ngIf`, I changed this:

- use the opposite logic of `ngIf` on [hidden]

```js
<p><button class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</button></p>
  <h2 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <div [hidden]="name !== 'John'" class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: its not really about changing the format , I am also using *ngFor for some components and its not working as well so that would not solve the issue. I am updated the question to add the precies code not working where I am using *ngFor

Comment: Hidding is just add style with display:none property but ngif is remove html from dom. So it is good practice to use ngIf instead of hidden whenever possible.

Comment: it needs a target DOM to let `data-open` work when `ngIf` condition is `true`, otherwise you need to reInit modal by yourself when DOM created

Comment: @user3701188 Is ngFor's source come from the Http or  any way to create dynamically?

Comment: @ChunbinLi I am taking it from a class which i already defined the variables so Im not thinking its as a result of the source of data I can post my ngInit if that would help

Comment: if you have free time would you create an online example on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @ChunbinLi how do I install foundation on the stackblitz

Comment: @ChunbinLi when I use static data it works but immediately I introduce and ngElement in the root element it stops working

Comment: Use dependencies, you can follow this guide https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/stackblitz-online-code-editor-for-angular-and-react-e327881b9d71